# Why won't Netbeans 9.0 show any error markers?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-9

I recently had to install Netbeans 9.0 to work on a gradle project at work, but unfortunately the editor won't show any error markers as i write code. Compilation errors are shown once i run, but i don't visualize them in the editor, even with obvious errors like not closing up a class with }. I also have netbeans 8.0.2 that i've installed through the installer, and error markers are shown correctly there. Has anyone encountered this problem, or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which Gradle plugin are you using? Which Java version are you using? Did you try NetBeans 10 (which is the current version)

Comment: I'm using  Gradle 2.0.1 and Java 1.8. I did not try on NetBeans 10 as i had problems installing the gradle plugin there.

Comment: There are two different Gradle plugins available, which one did you download?

Comment: Gradle Support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, please install **nb-javac** plugin.
I had same problem with NetBeans 11.2. It resolved after I installed this plugin and restarted the IDE.